# How do I convert a string of subtraction of numbers to an integer in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I know how to convert basic strings into integers, but how does one convert a string of subtraction (or any other mathematical function)? This doesn't work:

```
str_a = '10-5'
b = 3
c = int(str_a) + b
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10-5'
```

So how can I make it to work? c must be equal to 8.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval('10-5') + b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to evaluate `str_a` as the following:

```
import ast

str_a = '10-5'
c = ast.literal_eval(str_a) + 3
print(c)
str_a = '10+5-2' # you can use any operation not just subtraction and you can add as many numbers as you want
c = ast.literal_eval(str_a) + 2
print(c)
```

Output:

```
8
15
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
import re

str_a = '10-5'
vals = map(int, re.split("\W+", str_a))
new_value = vals[0] - vals[-1] + 3
```

Output:

```
8
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the builtin [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

```
str_a = '10-5'
left, right = str_a.split('-')
b = 3
c = (int(left) - int(right)) + b
```

Or use the [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) module:

```
import ast
str_a = '10-5'
b = 3
c = ast.literal_eval(str_a) + b
```

Answer (score 0):

Get them with a simple regular expression and then sum them up:

```
import re

str_a = '10-5'
rx = re.compile(r'[+-]?\d+')

a = sum([int(match.group(0)) for match in rx.finditer(str_a)])

b = 3
c = b + a
print(c)
# 8
```

Note that there are no security measurements yet (i.e. a float number won't work) - you'll need to precise your requirements here.